# Как изменить состояние в цикле ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, render

Есть массив `this.props.bets`, при попытке подсчёта коэффициента выскакивает ошибка `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`:

```
render() {
            let odd = 1;
            this.props.bets.map((bet) => {
                odd *= bet.odd;
            });

            this.setState({
                odds: odd
            });
            return (...)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну так получается, что вы в rendere вызываете setState. а setState - приводит к рендеру. Вот и бегаете по циклу

Используйте, например componentWillMount. ну а вообще, можно же прямо в конструкторе это дело решить

```
constructor(props) { 
    super(props) 
    const {bets} = this.props;
    let odd = 1;
    bets.map((bet) => {
            odd *= bet.odd;
    });

    this.state = {
        odds: odd
    }
}
```

Comment: Это не совсем подходит, т.к. в `this.props.bets` будут добавляться новые элементы

Comment: Хотя, нашёл выход: нужно использовать `componentWillReceiveProps`. но спасибо, что показали куда копать:)